# Get which chart is selected on activity

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using latest release of mpandroidchart library. I have 2 bar charts on single activity. chart1 & chart2 are the id's in XML (I don't want to use barchart list view). chart1 cosnist Counts value & chart2 consist dollars value. I am getting the values already. But I want to know that is it a dollar value or counts value. so I can display the toast according to chart selected.

This is my Sample code.

```
 public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {

    View view;
    TextView text;

    switch (e.getXIndex()) {
        case 0:

            if (toast != null)
                toast.cancel();

            toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "All Other Year Defectors: " +e.getVal(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            view = toast.getView();
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.all_odr_yr);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 950);
            toast.show();
            break;


        case 1:
            if (toast != null)
                toast.cancel();

            toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Last Year Defectors: " + e.getVal(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            view = toast.getView();
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.lst_yr_df);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 950);
            toast.show();
            break;
```

Comment: This is a big missing piece of mpandroidchart

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That seems to be quite difficult and hard to acheive with the library alone.

But what you could do is inline the listeners and use a separate listener for each chart, like this:

```
    countChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
            // COUNT CHART VALUE SELECTED
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() { }
    });

    dollarChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
            // DOLLAR CHART VALUE SELECTED
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() { }
    });
```

In that way you can **differentiate** between the different charts.

Comment: hi @Philip Thanks for great work. I am using latest library version. and I need to highlight specific values based on touch. what should be done in onValueSelected for this purpose. i need to highlight values as we do using setDrawValues. I hope you understand.

Comment: @Philipp Jahoda

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use inline listeners as Philip mentioned in his answer you can create a class implementing `onChartValueSelectedListener` and identify each chart with an ID.

```
    private class CustomOnValueSelectedListener implements OnChartValueSelectedListener {

    private int CHART_ID;

    public CustomOnValueSelectedListener() {}

    public CustomOnValueSelectedListener(int chart_id) {
        CHART_ID = chart_id;
    }

    @Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
        switch (CHART_ID) {
            case PIE_CHART_ID:
                break;
            case BAR_CHART_ID:
                break;
            case LINE_CHART_ID:
                break;
            default: 
                    //common code
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected() {
    }
}
```

You can now do this -

```
pieChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new CustomOnValueSelectedListener(PIE_ID));
barChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new CustomOnValueSelectedListener(BAR_ID));
lineChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new CustomOnValueSelectedListener(LINE_ID));


someOtherChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new CustomValueSelectedListener());
```

where `PIE_ID`, `LINE_ID` and `BAR_ID` are some unique integers.

This way your code is concise in case you have more than 3-4 charts to deal with else inline listeners are better.